# Network activity from crashlytics when my app is paused

Tags: android, performance, crashlytics, google-fabric, fabric.io

I am seeing following network activity when my app is in the paused state.

These are the URLs that Crashlitics is hitting:

https://api.crashlytics.com/spi/v1/platform/android/apps/<#application package name#>

https://e.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/events

I am attaching the trace for /events POST request from the profiler.

[image]

Why is Crashlytics making so many requests in the pause state? 
Will it have any impact on battery usage by the app in pause state?

Crashlytics Android SDK version is 1.4.1.19

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. These connections are expected. We send session ending details when possible. This does have a small impact on battery life, however we use logic that prevents us from activating the device radio when it is idle, so the impact on battery life is quite minimal. There are more connections when using our analytics tool then just crashlytics. If you want analytics disabled please contact our support team. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, Todd. Is there a reason to send these events so often? Is there something we are doing in the app that can trigger these events? I tried the same integration on a test app and it sents only a few events.  Only in my original app, it sends these events every 2 seconds continuously.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have analytics on for both apps or just the one sending more traffic?

Comment: It's the same config for both. I just build another app with same credentials to test.